# IPSec site-to-site VPN - behind router

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, openswan

I want to setup site-to-site VPN between two routers. On one site is an Ubuntu router marked "A", on the other site is a Cisco small business router marked "C". Here you can see the draft:

http://s17.postimg.org/bkdy2jnan/network.png

Site-to-site VPN with PSK is configured on both sites. On "A" we use openswan and the tunnel is established.

**The problem is that we can't access the remote subnets.** (No connection between 192.168.70.x and 192.168.10.y, no ping, etc.)

Here are the setup parameters on "A":

```
root@A:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.2
192.168.70.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.70.1


/etc/ipsec.conf
config setup
        dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
        protostack=netkey
        nat_traversal=yes
        plutodebug=all


conn cham
        authby=secret
        auto=add
        type=tunnel
        forceencaps=yes
        left=192.168.1.2
        leftid=78.x.y.z
        leftsubnet=192.168.70.0/24
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute
        right=62.a.b.c
        rightid=62.a.b.c
        rightsubnet=192.168.10.0/24
        rightnexthop=%defaultroute
        ike=aes-sha1;modp1024
        ikelifetime=28800s
        phase2=esp
        phase2alg=aes-sha1;modp1024
        salifetime=3600s




root@A:~# iptables -t nat -vnL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3748 packets, 293K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 959 packets, 128K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1039 packets, 79647 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 245 packets, 17799 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 3343  215K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0 




root@A:~# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 15635 packets, 1906K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 10 packets, 1040 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 120K   45M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth1    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 113K   11M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0  
   10  1040 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 4

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6928 packets, 1179K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination


/etc/sysctl.conf

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.conf.eth1.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.send_redirects = 0

root@A:/etc# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.70.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!